# Error “Undefined control sequence”

Tags: tables, errors, multirow

I need help. I'm building a table but I always get this error.
Here's my code:

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccccrrrr}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{8}{c}{Existing System} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Tangible Cost} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Intangible Cost} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Material} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Amount} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Material} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Amount} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{27}[2]{*}{Columnar Books (240 pieces/year)

Record Book
(100 pieces/year)

Bond Paper
(20 rims/year)

Pens
(30 boxes/year)

Folder
(40 rims/year)

Envelopes
(50 rims/year)

Receipts
(30 rims/year)

Ink
(12 bottles/year)

Total:
}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{27}[2]{*}{Php 15,840.00


Php   5,400.00


Php   4,800.00


Php   1,500.00


Php 19,000.00


Php 12,250.00


Php   4,350.00


Php      720.00


Php  63,860.00
}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{27}[2]{*}{Time

Effort

Manpower
                                                      }} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{27}[2]{*}{}} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Tangible Benefits} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Intangible Benefits} \\
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{More staff to handle the increasing amount of paper work.}} & \multicolumn{4}{l}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{Services }} \\
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{}          & \multicolumn{4}{l}{} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are using the `\multirow` command, but you haven't loaded the `multirow` package.